# Changing href with individual Link of another href of the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the following function to work with each article element of the same page otherwise the same link is applied to all article links, but it should be individual for all articles.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var firstlink = jQuery('.mega-rollover-content a.mega-link-wrapper');
  var secondlink = jQuery('h2.entry-title.mega-post-title a');
  firstlink.attr('href', secondlink.attr('href'));
});
```

What I've tried so far is this, but it won't work and console.log won't give me an error or something, it just won't work

```js
jQuery('article.mega-portfolio-post').each(function() {
  var firstlink = jQuery('.mega-rollover-content a.mega-link-wrapper');
  var secondlink = jQuery('h2.entry-title.mega-post-title a');
  firstlink.attr('href',secondlink.attr('href'));
});
```

here is the HTML Markup:

```html
<article class="mega-portfolio-post">
 <div class="mega-rollover-content">
  
  <a class="mega-link-wrapper" href="http://exampleurl.com/?portfolioexamplePDF.pdf" target="_blank" aria-label="Example"></a>
  
 </div>

<div class="mega-portfolio-content">
 <h2 class="entry-title mega-post-title" data-fontsize="20" data-lineheight="28">
 <a href="http://exampleurl.com/portfolio-items/example/?portfolioCats=26%2C27%2C28">Example</a>
 </h2>
</div>
</article>
```

what i want to achieve is that the "PDF Link" of each article is copied and applied to the "mega-portfolio-content" link

Comment: I would guess that you need to use the context of the first link to update the second, although its tricky to understand the exact problem you're trying to solve without seeing the HTML

Comment: show your html contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `each` loop you need to always make sure you are taking links for first and second link from appropriate articles only. Keeping this in mind you could use below code to achieve what you want;

```
jQuery('article.mega-portfolio-post').each(function() {
    var firstlink = jQuery(this).find('.mega-rollover-content a.mega-link-wrapper');
    var secondlink = jQuery(this).find('h2.entry-title.mega-post-title a');
    firstlink.attr('href', secondlink.attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: hmm i´m getting a syntax error for row 3, are you sure i can use just "." ? tried .find also but didnt work either

Comment: found the issue, the script had to be delayed a few seconds since the article links where loaded a few seconds after the main page, thanks for your help!